# How to define JPA Entity Class to load by query (not all records in table)

Tags: spring, jpa, entity

I have

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractFoo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...
```

and I have an Entity inheriting / extending it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
public class FooSomething extends AbstractFoo {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_something")
    private Something something;
    ...
```

fk_something may be null.

How do I define the Entity Class that it should know to fetch only Foos where fk_something is not null?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
@Query(SELECT *[fields of AbstractFoo + FooSomething] from <schema>.foo where fk_something is not null)
public class FooSomething extends AbstractFoo {
    ...
```

Whilst writing this question, I thought of a simple approach to simply define each time I fetch Foos via FooSomethingRepository to simply specify in query that "something" is not null.

Yet still I'm interested to know if there is a more formal way to define this on Entity Class level

Thank-you

Comment: `@Query` is not the JPA API, so no idea what it is doing there. You simply write a JPQL query for objects of type `FooSomething` where this field is not null. And where is the difficulty in that? You can define that in a named query if you wish it hardcoded statically

Comment: There is nothing standard in JPA to do that. You could use a view, or you could use a proprietary feature of your JPA engine. But you haven't said what is is.

Comment: Thank you for referring to my question@Billy Frost

Comment: Thank you for referring to my question. @Billy Frost - I meant something like Query and not something which exists.. surely enough the closest to what I was looking for was NamedQuery.

Comment: @JB Nizet wrote "There is nothing standard in JPA to do that" - that's an answer that satisfies me. Is there a way to select your comment as the answer to my question?